# bitcoin core test config error

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I tried configuring the bitcoin core test by editing the bitcoin.conf file with the required credentials.

Earlier, before the writing the test credentials it was a running full node.
now the error is

config settings for rpcport only applied on the test network when in [test] section.

(picture uploaded for reference)[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are choosing to use network specific sections in your config file, Core requires you to have certain arguments in those sections, such as `rpcport`. So you need to move `rpcport` into a network specific section.

Answer (score 0):

for every UTX token ( bitcoind and the beyond ) for mode test net ("testnet=1") 
default port will be used and you can't change it because by default .

> Default Bitcoin network protocol listen port is 18333 (instead of 8333)
>   Default RPC connection port is 18332 (instead of 8332)